# Chaining async tasks with ContinueWith in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Despite `async` and `await` have been out for a while now, and since being a long time C# dev, I still have difficulties really understanding how they work and when to use them. So I am writing some test code!

I am trying to **asynchronoulsy** call a **task A** from the **main** thread, **then** call **task B** when task A finishes, **then** call **task C**.

In pseudo-code, this would be something like :

```
RunAsync(TaskA())
    .Then(TaskB())
        .Then(TaskC());
```

I have written the following example, but in does not behave as I expected.  Instead or running A then B then C, it runs A, then B **and** C are running in **parallel**.

The C# snippet is the following (details below):

```
Task
  .Run(async () => await LongTaskAsync("A"))
  .ContinueWith(async (taskA) => await LongTaskAsync("B"))
  .ContinueWith(async (taskB) => await LongTaskAsync("C"));
```

I printed out thread ids, and I have :

- Id 1 for main thread
- Id 2 for task A
- Id 4 for tasks B AND C
- No Id 3 (or some place I ignore)

Here's the code :

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTests
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DateTime _start;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _start = DateTime.Now;
            Log("======= Main thread starts ======");
            Log($"Main thread ID : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            // Start a stack of aynchronous calls
            Task
                .Run(async () => await LongTaskAsync("A"))
                .ContinueWith(async (taskA) => await LongTaskAsync("B"))
                .ContinueWith(async (taskB) => await LongTaskAsync("C"));

            Log("====== Main thread returns ======");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }  

        static async Task LongTaskAsync(string name)
        {
            Log($"Long async task {name} starts");
            Log($"{name} thread ID : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            for(var i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
            {
                Log($"Task {name} says {i}");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }            
            Log($"Long async task {name} returns");
        }

        static void Log(string text)
        {
            var elpased = (int)(DateTime.Now - _start).TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine($"[+{elpased.ToString().PadLeft(4,'0')}] {text}");
        }
    }
}
```

And the console output :

```
[+0003] ======= Main thread starts ======
[+0009] Main thread ID : 1
[+0016] ====== Main thread returns ======
[+0022] Long async task A starts
[+0024] A thread ID : 3
[+0024] Task A says 1
[+1028] Task A says 2
[+2029] Task A says 3
[+3030] Task A says 4
[+4031] Task A says 5
[+5032] Long async task A returns
[+5034] Long async task B starts
[+5034] B thread ID : 4
[+5034] Task B says 1
[+5035] Long async task C starts
[+5036] C thread ID : 4
[+5036] Task C says 1
[+6036] Task C says 2
[+6036] Task B says 2
[+7037] Task C says 3
[+7037] Task B says 3
[+8038] Task B says 4
[+8038] Task C says 4
[+9039] Task C says 5
[+9039] Task B says 5
[+10040] Long async task C returns
[+10040] Long async task B returns
```

Comment: Why in the world are you making all of the lambdas `async`, when they don't do anything, but are opposed to using `async` in the one method that could actually use it?

Comment: As I told in the intro text, I am not comfortable with async programmation neither in C# nor in any language. So misunderstood usage of these keywords is highly possible.

About the dupllication, I don't consider this question as a duplicate, since the specifics of mine is to chain several ContinueWith, while other involve a single call of it.

Basically, my question is "should one consider `ContinueWith` as the C# equivalent of Then() on Primises in JS/TS".

Comment: The fact that you need to apply the solution three times, and not just once, doesn't make it a fundamentally different question.  If you're doing the thing that needs to be fixed three times, then apply the solution three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the calls to be made sequentially, just `await` them:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await LongTaskAsync("A");
    await LongTaskAsync("B");
    await LongTaskAsync("C");
});
```

Sample output:

```
[+0000] ======= Main thread starts ======
[+0001] Main thread ID : 1
[+0015] ====== Main thread returns ======
[+0020] Long async task A starts
[+0020] A thread ID : 3
[+0020] Task A says 1
[+1021] Task A says 2
[+2021] Task A says 3
[+3022] Task A says 4
[+4022] Task A says 5
[+5024] Long async task A returns
[+5024] Long async task B starts
[+5024] B thread ID : 4
[+5024] Task B says 1
[+6025] Task B says 2
[+7026] Task B says 3
[+8026] Task B says 4
[+9027] Task B says 5
[+10028] Long async task B returns
[+10028] Long async task C starts
[+10028] C thread ID : 3
[+10028] Task C says 1
[+11029] Task C says 2
[+12029] Task C says 3
[+13030] Task C says 4
[+14032] Task C says 5
[+15032] Long async task C returns
```

However, the above code would fail if any of the tasks fail (due to `await`). If you want these to always run, you will need an uglier approach:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    LongTaskAsync("A").ContinueWith((taskA) =>
    {
        LongTaskAsync("B").ContinueWith((taskB) => LongTaskAsync("C"));
    });
});
```

The difference between this and your actual code is to what task you assign the continuation work.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected, and is so much more readable than my version.

Comment: what happens when one of the `Task` throws the exception, others will not execute, which is not the Case with `ContinueWith`. Moreover wrapping await inside a `Task.Run` has little practical use

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The OP did not mention they want to handle cases when the task fail. And yes, it does have the practical use of running the Tasks in a Thread Pool Thread.

Comment: Its better to make the whole chain including Main async, rather than wrapping inside `Task.Run` and using one pool thread to execute async operation

Comment: @MrinalKamboj No, making `Main` `async` is the same as using `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which does **not** run on a Thread Pool Thread. Different scenarios different solutions

Comment: @Camilo correct, I don't want to deal neither with exceptions nor with previous results. As a test example, I expect tasks to be safe and independant. I just wanted to chain them, but wrap that whole chain in an async call.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj When testing async in Console apps, there is always the issue that the main cannot (yet) be async. So there must be some initial call to initiate the async process.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto `ConfigureAwait().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` was just a workaround, which is more used when you cannot make Main as async. In fact your solution doesn't introduce that either, you seem to be fine with Console.Read

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I would suggest you to copy the code to a new project and try it out, I am completely certain of what I posted. I will post an edit though

Comment: @kall2sollies who told you Main cannot be made `async` from C#7.1 onward you can do like this `async static Task Main(string[] args)`

Comment: @kall2sollies Please see the edit, now the tasks are independent of the result of the previous

Comment: @kall2sollies, if you allow another set of response (you seemed to have blocked further response), then I can surely provide another set of option where Main entry point is also Async and different between ContinueWith and series of await, as done now

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Don't be fooled to much. `async Task Main` in c# 7.1 is the syntactic sugar equivalent of `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` (the compiler does this for you). You should read the release notes

Comment: @MrinalKamboj about async main: as you point it out, it's a recent feature since included in C#7.1. My code runs against C#7.0 compiler (and I don't know why since both dotnet core sdk and vs 2017 are very up-to-date !)
About further answers: I didn't lock anything, but my question has been marked as duplicate, I think this is why you can't post further answer. I voted for reopening.

Comment: @kall2sollies You need to edit the project properties for that (project > build > advanced> from latest major to latest minor). But I do not think that is relevant to your question, at all.

Comment: For C#7.x one can also add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in the .csproj

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Generated IL code suggests the internal call to the `TaskAwaiter.IsCompleted` followed by `TaskAwaiter.GetResult`, but that's to avoid explicit call to the `System.RunTime.CompilerServices` API by the user program, which is CLR prerogative not to provide a syntactic sugar. Nonetheless async calls within `Task.Run` may work for Console with null synchronization context, but is a bad approach for most of the systems with synchronization context like asp.net. To prove your point, provide valid examples and links, not expletives

Comment: @kall2sollies didn't realize earlier that your question is marked duplicate. Now anyway the current answer contains the important difference, that how ContinueWith is different from set of await calls. You can certainly target a specific language version compiler. Do consider making your program entry point as Async, which is possible for ASP.Net mvc / api controllers, Console Main, which is an ideal way to initiate a non blocking async call. You can even plan to use `Task.WhenAll` or `WhenAny` to execute multiple Async calls together and await the representative Task